Problem with cros_val_score with Linear Regression
I have this code where I don't understand where the error is when I calculate the cross_val_score.
You can find the code at the end.
When I insert X and Y into cross_val_score I get this output=
[-1.04310278e+25 -9.02663688e-01 -5.58849445e-01 -4.67666181e-01
  -5.31695826e-01 -5.38521348e-01 -4.88145909e-01 -9.43066823e-01
  -8.05226210e-01 -1.08907648e+00]

if instead I insert x_train and y_train (even after having split them with for example a test_size=0.01, therefore very similar to X and Y) I obtain the result for cross_val_score of:
[-0.71077296 -0.55292557 -0.61305045 -0.56387715 -0.69411482 -0.6876596
 -0.58946027 -0.65684074 -0.70967388 -0.887881  ]

They are very different results and I don't understand where the problem is.
The shapes of X are (18994, 12)
of Y (18994, 2) and if I have a testsize of 0.2 for x_train we have (15195, 12) and y_train (15195, 2).
Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import geopy
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
model=LinearRegression()
mulregressor=MultiOutputRegressor(model)
data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\...\file.xlsx")
def usestandardization(data):
    scaleStandard=StandardScaler()
    data=scaleStandard.fit_transform(data) 
    data=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["bedrooms","bathrooms","squareFootage","yearBuilt","price",
                                "listedDate","removedDate","daysOnMarket","latitude",
                               "longitude","Condo","Multi-Family","Single Family","Townhouse","bathrooms_ratio"])
    return data

datastand=usestandardization(data)
X=datastand.drop(["daysOnMarket"], axis=1)
X=X.drop(["removedDate"], axis=1)
X=X.drop(["price"], axis=1).values
Y=datastand[["daysOnMarket","price"]].values

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)
k_fold_acc= cross_val_score(mulregressor, x_train,y_train,cv=10,scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
print(k_fold_acc)


It's quite possible that there's nothing wrong with your code, and that the one extreme score from all of X is caused by an outlier that got thrown into the test set. What happens if you use different random_states in the cross-val or the train-test split?

@BenReiniger I apologize for the late reply, as soon as I am in front of the computer where I have the program I will try to set another random state.
I had also thought about outliers, however I tried with x_train and y_train using 0.99 of X and Y. Basically x_train had about 70 elements less than X(same for Y)
Now I wonder, is it possible that the results of the errors are so greatly affected by some outlier? Let's assume there are 50 outliers. Can they really have such a large role on a dataset of 19,000 data? (I looked closely at the data and it doesn't seem like there is any crazy data)

It does strike me as unlikely, but I can't think of anything else offhand. Can you share the data somewhere? Or maybe try cross_validate with return_estimator=True so you can inspect the coefficients of the bad model?

I dont know where the error is. I also tried """x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.0001,random_state=42)""". here x_train and y_train have only one element less than X and Y but I still receive the same results @BenReiniger
